# Preimage of a proper morphism

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, schemes, abelian-varieties, morphism

We know that proper  morphisms of  varieties take  closed subsets to closed subsets. What can I say of the preimage  of a proper morphism? For example, if I know  that $f(g(x))$  is an uncountable closed variety, Can  I say  that since $f$ is proper, the preimage $g(x)$ is necessarily an uncountable closed variety?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Did this come up in some other problem?

Comment: Yes, @HankScorpio to know  this  can be useful to complete  the proof  of a theorem :).